# How to include variable length images as UITableViewCell background in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uitableview

I have to include a speech bubble as shown in the attached image as background in a table view cell.

[image]

But the bubbles keep varying in height based on the text length. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the cell height according to the text length, I usually make a class method in my custom `UITableViewCell` that do this.

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGFloat cellHeight = 0.0;

    // calculate cellHeight height according to text length 

    // here you set the maximum width and height you want the text to be
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(kTextMaxWidth, kTextMaxHeight);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:TEXT_FONT 
                        constrainedToSize:maxSize 
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

    // set some minimum height for the cell (if the text is too short..)
    cellHeight = MAX(size.height, kMinHeight);  

    // here I usually increase the cellHeight according to the cell's other subviews
    // because if you have other subviews under/above the bubble you need to count them 
    // and add height to the cell...  
    cellHeight += kSomeSpaceToAdd;

    return cellHeight;
}
```

Then u call this method in   `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Message *currMessage = [self.myMessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGFloat height = [MyCustomCell cellHeightForText:currMessage.text];

    return height;
}
```

Of course you should also set the bubble image frame according to the text length, I something do this in the custom cell `layoutSubviews` method, at this point the cell height already set so you can use it (self.bounds.size.height) to set your bubble image accordingly..